# Links in HTTPS site are always HTTP

Tags: bug, https

All links in the HTTPS Ask Ubuntu, except for the navbar, are HTTP. Even if I specifically open `https://askubuntu.com`, navigating anywhere returns me to HTTP. Neither do I want it, nor it is an expected behavior for HTTPS site. And since it's supported why is HTTP even active anyway? Everything should be redirected to HTTPS by default.

Comment: SE is not yet officially supporting HTTPS, although they claim to be working about it... maybe. The [tag wiki of `ssl` on Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/ssl/info) basically says it all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Solution

**If you need HTTPS to protect your privacy** on all pages of Ask Ubuntu, install the [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) browser extension and it will modify all requests by replacing `http:` with `https:`.

## Explanation

This is a weakness of Stack Exchange and should be corrected. They might need to invest money on better hardware and in software engineering to support the huge number of TLS 1.2 connections, otherwise some visitors may experience timeout or certificate errors.

HTTPS Everywhere has a [special rule](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere/atlas/domains/stackoverflow.com.html) for Ask Ubuntu and you will not have connection problems.
Your browser will show a green lock, click on it to see: 128 bit TLS 1.2 encryption from `DigiCert Inc.`.

## Suggestion

If you use *Mozilla Firefox* (or *Iceweasel*) and the privacy is a huge priority of your LAN, visit `about:config` from your address bar and search for the option `security.tls.version.min`. Insert a higher number to prevent some HTTPS degradation attacks.

Comment: **Update**: the latest releases of Mozilla Firefox also support [HTTPS-only mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/https-only-prefs).